# Jenkins Multijob execution showing the parent job as completed even its sub jobs are still running

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In Jenkins multijob execution showing the parent job execution showing completed even though sub jobs are still running, Please let me know.

I want the parent job to wait until all the job get finishes and if any of the job fail then parent job also show with red color as failed.

Please find the below structure as I have configured in jenkins. Here Multijob is parent and its should wait until below its child jobs get finished, both child jobs will run parallel and its configured in same phase.

MultiJob    (Parent)
    apache_jmeter    (child1)
    auto_perf_jmeter_scripts (child2)

Comment: How do you have the sub-jobs configured in the multijob? Are the sub-jobs themselves triggering other jobs that you want to "wait" on?

Comment: Hi ,I have edited my above question please check it and let me know your suggestion.

Comment: What version of Jenkins and the Multijob plugin are you using?